# org.jdom2.IllegalNameException

Tags: java, xml, jdom

I'm using jdom2, and it pops out error when try to set the element value with space.

part of the code code goes like this:

```
 Element feature = new Element("feature");    
 feature.setAttribute("name", "semantic role");
```

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.jdom2.IllegalNameException: The name "semantic role" is not legal for JDOM/XML attributes: XML names cannot contain the character " ".
```

Comment: What don't you understand?

Comment: I don't understand 2 things : **1)** according to the Javadoc, you can have this problem only if the first argument of `Element.setAttribute(s1,s2)` is not valid. Here, the problems seems to come from the second. **2)** On my side, this code is executed without error. Nevertheless, if I try `feature.setAttribute("semantic role", "name");` instead, I got this error (and this is exactly the expected behavior). Are you sure that you did not reverse the 2 arguments?

Comment: Edit : I upvoted your answer so that you get enough reputation to answer in comments.

Comment: Please double-check your errors. I copy/pasted your code, and it works for me.